# Digital SIgnal Processing in Android

Tags: android, signal-processing

I am searching for digital audio signal processing library for android. I want to built an app which process input audio signal and plays back to speaker in real time. Is there any ready DSP library/Game engine which has such functionality ?

Comment: If you want some background on real-time audio on Android, it might help to watch all of the videos referenced in this link: https://source.android.com/devices/audio/latency_app.html#resources

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by 'real-time' on Android -- if you mean 10 ms or less audio latency, Android OS is not quite there. But developers can do a lot to lower latency:

http://superpowered.com/android-audio-low-latency-primer

http://superpowered.com/androidaudiopathlatency/

Also, see audio latency data table here:

http://superpowered.com/latency/

Full disclosure: I am cofounder of Superpowered

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of processing you want to do, check out [Superpowered](http://superpowered.com/#axzz3j4XMskhp).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to develop an application which required 1D signal processing techniques as provided in the scipy.signal library with processes ranging from processes like convolution and correlation to filters and peak detection.

Since I could not find any library for this available, I started writing my own library called [jDSP](https://psambit9791.github.io/jDSP/). You may want to go through this library, if *scipy.signal* is the kind of library you are looking for. 
As of now, it is only limited to 1D signal.